# AJAX calling different action on controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, action

AJAX method :

```
$(".GetF").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('@Url.Action("test1", "flyer")', { "selectedIds": "1"})
                    .done(function (data) {
                        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                    });
});
```

Controller Action :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult test1(string selectedIds)
    {
       ......
       return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Everytime i make this ajax call, it calls following method only

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FViewModel vm)
{
}
```

I tried changing method to HTTPGet and ajax call to type='get' which also doesn't work.

I'm not able to identify what exactly is the issue here. Please note, there are no submit button or forms on the page. The element for which click event is written is just normal link.

Comment: Store posting URL in a varriable and chaek its value may be it is null.

Comment: @RajanMishra : There are no variables for url. If i call simply by "/flyer/test1" then also its not working.

Comment: Are you sure it is `@Url.Action("test1", "flyer")` instead of `@Url.Action("test1", "Flyer")`? Also try `{ selectedIds: "1"}` too.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : no luck with above suggestions.

Comment: try this instead   $.post("test1/flyer", JSON.stringify({ "selectedIds": "1"}))

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with your routing.
Please try posting to the endpoint without using Url.Action() to help rule out routing issues.
e.g  $.post('http://localhost:53149/test1', { selectedIds: "1"})

Obviously you'll need to replace the port (53149) above with your own but this should help find out if this is where the issue lies. 
If the problem persist with the direct link then please check your routing table and make sure your test1 method would be hit before being captured by your Index Method.

Answer (score 0):

`.GetF` class is coming from a button ?

I think its a button you are clicking and this buttons `type` is submit and you are working in your Index page.

change your button `type="button"` and you dont need to use `e.preventDefault();`

```
$.post('@Url.Action("test1", "flyer")',
                {
                    selectedIds: '1',
                }).done(function (data) {
});
```

I think this will fix your problem.

Comment: No. It's not a button. It's a link only.<a href="#" class="GetF">...</a>